# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:

Tags: java, junit, mockito, matcher

My method in the service and test class :

```
public void updateSubModuleOrder(Long[] data, Long moduleSysId, Long userId) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            SubModule subModule=new SubModule();

            int temp = i + 1;
            userSubmodule.setDsplySeq(temp);
            userSubModuleDao.saveOrUpdate(userSubmodule);
@Test
public void testupdateSubModuleOrder(){
    UserModuleServiceImpl userModuleServiceImpl = new UserModuleServiceImpl();
    UserSubModuleDao userSubModuleDao = mock(User//set the required param ,some code here//
    UserSubModuleId userSubModuleId=new UserSubModuleId();
    //some code//
    when(userSubModuleDao.findById((any(UserSubModuleId.class)),false)).thenReturn(userSubModule);
    when(userSubModuleDao.saveOrUpdate(any(UserSubModule.class))).thenReturn(null);
    userModuleServiceImpl.updateSubModuleOrder(data, moduleSysId, userId);

};*
```

the error I get is

```
FAILED: testupdateSubModuleOrder
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at com.TestUserModuleServiceImpl.testupdateSubModuleOrder(TestUserModuleServiceImpl.java:267)
```

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:

```
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
```

When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:

```
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

the method `findbyID` is a baseDao method which my dao extends . It is not a final or static but still I'm getting this problem.

Comment: Ensure you have **all** your arguments are using matchers (`anyXX` or `eq`): `userSubModuleDao.findById((any(UserSubModuleId.class)),false)` looks suspicious

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mockito: InvalidUseOfMatchersException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845690/mockito-invaliduseofmatchersexception)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You either have to specify *no* matchers, or *all* the arguments need matches. So this:

```
when(userSubModuleDao.findById((any(UserSubModuleId.class)),false))
```

should be:

```
when(userSubModuleDao.findById(any(UserSubModuleId.class), eq(false)))
```

(I've removed the redundant brackets from around the `any` call.)

From the [`Matchers` documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html):

> **Warning:**
>
> If you are using argument matchers, **all arguments** have to be provided by matchers.

Comment: When i try to use doRetrun().when(), it gives me following error. TestUserModuleServiceImpl.testupdateSubModuleOrder(TestUserModuleServiceImpl.java:270)
E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!  anyways i had revert back to the initial line and its working now.

Comment: The latest Matchers document http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html. (Mockito 1.x)

Comment: My case is caused by the method access level being `package-level` https://stackoverflow.com/a/57302399/8034839, changing the method to `protected` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was my target method to mock was a `final` method.

The error message says

```
Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

solution:

change `public final void foo() {}` --> `public void foo() {}`