# How to mock and verify method with argument T

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, verify, parameterized-types

I have a method:

```
public V doSomething(T t, Class<V> classV){}
```

how can I invoke this method with the mockObject and verify it?

I'm trying like this:

```
when(mockObject.doSomething(any(MyConcreteT.class), AnotherConcrete.class).
                thenReturn(obj);    
verify(mockObject).doSomething(any(MyConcreteT.class), AnotherConcrete.class);
```

but receive an error

> InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Invalid use of argument matchers!

appreciate any(help)

Comment: Is this the complete error message?

Comment: for some reason, unfortunately I can't provide full stack trace

Comment: Not the stack trace, but there should be a detailed error message.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845690/mockito-invaliduseofmatchersexception

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Mockito requires all parameters to be non-matchers or all parameters to be matchers. It doesn't allow to mix them. (A detailed error message should tell you this, though.)

Try:

```
when(mySpy.doSomething(any(MyConcreteT.class), eq(AnotherConcrete.class)).
                thenReturn(obj);    
verify(mySpy).doSomething(any(MyConcreteT.class), eq(AnotherConcrete.class));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. There is not a spy but a mock object which invoke my method. I tried to do as you said, but the error is the same.

Comment: I should use 

`when(mockObject.doSomething(any(MyConcreteT.class), any(AnotherConcrete.class.getClass())).
                thenReturn(obj);    
verify(mockObject).doSomething(any(MyConcreteT.class), any(AnotherConcrete.class.getClass()));`