# InvalidUseOfMatchersException Error in Junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have below method in my service class -

```
public List<Employee> getEmployee(String deptId){
    try{
        DepartmentResponse department = departmentClient.employeeData(deptId);

        return isNull(department) ? newArrayList() : department.getEmployee();

    }catch(CstomeException ex) {
        log.error("Some Error Message");
    }catch(RetryableException ex) {
        log.error("Some Error Message");
    }
    return newArrayList();
}
```

When I am trying to mock this method like below -

```
when(departmentService.getEmployee(anyString()))
        .thenReturn(newArrayList(Employee.builder.build()));
```

I am getting below error -

```
 org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException
```

I tried with this also.

```
when(departmentService.getEmployee(any(String.class)))
        .thenReturn(newArrayList(Employee.builder.build()));
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845690/mockito-invaliduseofmatchersexception

Comment: Does `Employee.builder.build()` use the `departmentService` at all?  In other words, are you trying to use your mock, while you're actually stubbing it?

Comment: put the whole stacktrace to see the root cause

Comment: In your test class, is departmentService a mock (eg annotated with @Mock )?  Could you paste that declaration, and your test method?